# Is there a way to count number of opportunity line items on opportunity with out generating event(like formula field)?

Tags: apex, roll-up-summary

Is there a way to count number of opportunity line items on opportunity with out generating event(example: formula field)?
I know we have ways to get it (using Rollup summary 2.Apex). But both of them are generate events and it's let's fire triggers on opportunity. As per our business we should not fire  triggers.
Please suggest.

Comment: It is not for display purpose, I need to use this field to make decision whether the opportunity can be deleted or not based on this count (ideally before delete trigger on opportunity). Can you please comment on solution which doesnot involve event generation to count number of line items, Thanks

Comment: Using apex should not fire your triggers, if you are simply getting the count with a query. Only actions `insert`, `update`, `delete`, and `undelete` on the record will fire triggers. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005cC6QAI

Comment: Do you want to prevent deletion of an opportunity if it has line items? If so, you can use the field `HasOpportunityLineItem`

Answer (score 0):

No, formulas can't count children, so you need a rollup summary field or Apex. However, if this is only for display purposes, you could write a Visualforce page or Lightning Component to display any manner of data, or you could put a report on the page layout.